# How to automatically print the value of variables by changing the last character (number)

Tags: php

How to automatically print the value of variables by changing the last character (number)

```
    $risk_1 = "aaaa";
    $risk_2 = "bbbb";
    $risk_3 = "cccc";

for ($x = 1; $x <= 2; $x++) {
  echo "$risk_".$x;
  echo "<br>";
}
```

I want to get this

```
     aaaa
     bbbb
     cccc
```

Comment: Don't do that!  Use an array, that's what they are for.

Comment: This is just an array with extra steps.

Answer (score 0):

we can use variable variables in php to dynamically create variables like below

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 3; $x++) {
  $var_name = "risk_" . $x;
  echo $$var_name;
  echo "<br>";
}
```

[Sandbox example here](https://phpsandbox.io/n/blue-nute-gunray-tcpro)

Comment: Or `echo ${"risk_" . $x};`

Comment: or even echo ${"risk_{$x}"}; can be done

Comment: Yeah, that was more typing ;-)